# MPMoviePlayerController shows no picture when playing online video

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I used a MPMoviePlayerController to play online video in another view controller. It works well most times. But sometimes the player plays video without pictures while the sound and progress bar are working. After the black screen occurs, if I change to play another video, it will often works well. Can someone tell me what's the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: I solved the problem by replacing the video of type m3u8 with that of mp4.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use MPMoviePlayerController to play online video.
It is the best controller for playing online videos.

Comment: Use `AVPlayerViewController` as `MPMoviePlayerController ` is deprecated in ios9.

Comment: Sorry that I misspelled MPMoviePlayerViewController to UIMoveiPlayerViewController. I have corrected it. I didn't use AVPlayerViewController because my app should support ios 7.0